# How to change CTRL+TAB behaviour in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I am new to PyCharm and I am setting my favorite shortcuts to use it fluidly. I would like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to behave like they do in Google Chrome, i.e. you move to the next or previous tab (file). Right now it looks to me as if it is moving according to the most recent used files.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Click on `File`, `Settings`, `Keymap`. Or `Preferences` in Mac.
2. Type in `select tab` to filter the relevant shortcut keys.
3. Override "Select Next Tab" with `ctrl-tab` and "Select Previous Tab" with `ctrl-shift-tab`

[image]